# shell script did read file using cat

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reading Manthan Status
echo "Manthan cat started"
cat /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/my_mon.txt | while read LINE

do
    echo "Inside my loop"
    echo "$LINE"
    if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
        echo "startedif_my"
        sudo lsof -n -i:8082 | grep LISTEN | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq |sudo  xargs kill -9;
        sleep 30;
        sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
        break
    fi
done


#Reading Panel Status
echo "Panel cat started"
cat /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/panel_mon.txt | while read LINE

do
    echo "Inside panel loop"
    echo "$LINE"
    if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then

        sudo lsof -n -i:8082 | grep LISTEN | awk '{ print $2 }' | uniq |sudo  xargs kill -9;
        sleep 30;
        sudo sh /var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/sym --port 8082 --server;
        break
    fi
done
echo "end of script"
```

When I run the above script the script reads first file and echoing the $Line. After that it is not reading the second file and it is just going to last echo which is end of the script.

Can you please suggest why?

Comment: Did you verify whether the 2nd file has some contents ?

Comment: I've seen this a lot when the text file was created in DOS/Windows and does not have a line feed at the end of the file, which causes the read to skip the line

Comment: I have checked that it got the content as false and it is not at all going inside do for checking if condition. It is running in UBUNTU and the file is created by a php in ubuntu.I have checked the permissions too.

Comment: Do you reach the `echo "Panel cat started"` line?

Comment: 1) in second while statement try to loop over the first file, so you will loop over my_mon.txt files two times. Check whether it works. 2) compare outputs of `ls -al` command for my_mon.txt and panel_mon.txt files

Comment: This probably won't fix your problem, but `while read line; do ...; done < file` is preferred over `cat file | while read line; do ...; done`.

Answer (score 1):

```
value=$(</var/www/symmetric-ds-3.1.6/bin/my_mon.txt)
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo"Inside loop"
fi
```

This worked for me. Culprit is cat I guess