# Different behavior from ubuntu server and ubuntu client on windows

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reading

cat /home/radiare/Desktop/first.txt | while read LINE

do
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo "Inside first loop"
break
fi
done

cat /home/radiare/Desktop/second.txt | while read LINE

do
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo "Inside second loop"
break
fi
done
```

In ubuntu client, I could able to execute this script and echo inside if statements are properly working. I did the same thing in ubuntu server it is not going inside the if statement. only difference is I run using sudo on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: huh, almost the same code as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848147/shell-script-did-read-file-using-cat . Does the file being listed exist on the server? and if it exists on the server, does root have access to the file (e.g. remote file system)? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I didn't see any errors. The file also executed using sudo permissions. the other files it is accessing also have permissions to read write. It is running till the end but it is not going inside the if loop. which means it is not reading specified txt documents. When I run the cat in the console and echo the content it is returning contents properly.

Comment: Exactly the same files on the client and server? I mean bytewise identical?

Comment: `sudo cat /home/radiare/Desktop/first.txt` and the same for second.txt need to show the same content as the client, and if you see a line like `false%`, then it means there's no new line at the end of the file, which is why it's not being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

strange, I cannot comment, but can only "answer".

What I think is that the file is of MS DOS format, when you run the script under ubuntu client on windows, it understand the MS DOS format, and treat it accordingly.

However, on the server side, when you use read LINE to read in the lines in MS DOS format, you will also read in the trailing \r character.

I bet that's the reason. Try

```
tr -d '\015' /home/radiare/Desktop/first.txt
```

first and run your script again.